# Docusign - api get utl to download document

Tags: docusignapi

I need api to create URL link for download document of envelope.

I found this api:
  `GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}`

But this api just return the file and i what a URL i can download the file (of course with expired time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint you're looking for is:

```
POST /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient
```

You will need to provide in the body information about the recipient, see here for details:

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient

We also have code examples in various langagues to show you how to do this here:

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-request-a-signature-via-email

Comment: Thank you for this info! I have tried it and it took me to the page on the docusign site where the signed doc is displayed and I could click on the download button there. But is there a way to generate a similar url in the same fashion, and my users can open it in their browser and save the file right away?

Comment: You could download the document yourself, save it, and present it to user however you want. 
Follow this to figure out how to download documents - https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-downloading-documents